# MBED_TLS returning an error of 0xFFFFBC80

Tags: c, rsa, mbed

Using the mbded_tls library I am getting an error code returned from the device of 0xFFFFBC80.  I assume the leading F's are irrelevant, but I can't find any error code of BC80 (or its inverse, 4380) in the documentation.  I can see there is mention of summation of high-level and low-level codes in the docs but it is not easy to pinpoint.  The error is almost certainly to do with the verification of a signature file signed with private key and being checked by the device using the public key, but without more specific detail I can't determine where my error is.

Regards,

Comment: Which function returns the error? Can you try to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
0xFFFFBC80
```

From [mbed_tls/error.h](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/include/mbedtls/error.h#L28):

```
 * Currently we try to keep all error codes within the negative space of 16
 * bits signed integers to support all platforms (-0x0001 - -0x7FFF). In
 * addition we'd like to give two layers of information on the error if
 * possible.
 *
 * For that purpose the error codes are segmented in the following manner:
 *
 * 16 bit error code bit-segmentation
 *
 * 1 bit  - Unused (sign bit)
 * 3 bits - High level module ID
 * 5 bits - Module-dependent error code
 * 7 bits - Low level module errors
```

`0xFFFFBC80` is `-0x4380` and that is `0100 0011 1000 0000` in binary

That gives us:

```
 - 1 bit unused - 0
 - 3 bits high level module id - 0b100
 - 5 bits module dependent error code - 0b00111
 - 7 bits low level module errors  - 0b0000000
```

Now we can dwell into finding and interpreting single bits and reading mbed_tls sources... or just be a smartie and do `grep -r 4380` on mbed_tls sources, which will yield the line in [rsa.h](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/include/mbedtls/rsa.h):

```
 #define MBEDTLS_ERR_RSA_VERIFY_FAILED                     -0x4380  /**< The PKCS#1 verification failed. */
```

So PKCS#1 verification failed in your code.

But, really, why to do that by hand? You can just use the [mbedtls_strerror](https://tls.mbed.org/api/error_8h.html) function:

```
char buf[1024];
mbedtls_strerror(0xFFFFBC80, buf, sizeof(buf));
printf("result: %s\n", buf);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that - I hadn't interpreted the return codes correctly, ironically I had the negative value for 0xFFFFBC80 down as -(437F)  :  off by one bit.  I knew the error code return was  potentially a composite of a high level module and low level function call, but none matched that particular code, obvious now!  The device programmer who I am writing the client code for isn't a great believer in returning meaningful failure information, but that's another issue...  Thanks for your help in pointing out my error!